# Visual Studio C++ Can't include additional directory within same solution or outside folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio, include

So I'm learning C++ this semester and right on the first laboratory I got a problem which nor me, nor my prof could solve. Our task was really basic. Create a solution, create a project in which create a function and a header file. In the header file is the declaration of the function. Then create a new project (in same solution), add the old one as a reference. Now comes the part which gave me a headache. Add the path of the folder of the .h file into the "*Additional Include Directories*" section. Well I do that and nothing. I tried diferent locations, but nothing worked. Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Here are some pictures:

[The "code". It is not much](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmh2a.jpg)

[The path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCqJH.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean nothing?  Are you getting an error or warning?  If so, tell us what it is.

Comment: I get an error, that it can't find a .h filed named like that. I edited the post with pictures.

Comment: That looks like it should work.  Can you bring up a cmd window outside of Visual Studio and try to change directories to the one you have specified.  It may help you find a typo or some other issue.

Comment: I copied the path and it works in cmd. https://imgur.com/3nUxurI

Comment: And even when i copy in the full path like '#include "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\programming\cpp\labor1\StaticLibraryExample_v2\MyMathFuncs_v2\mySin.h" ', then it works. Looks like only the VS including doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled VisualStudio and now it works prefctly. FML

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the directory is listed, you still have to reference header with `#include "yourHeader.h"` wherever you want to use the forward-declared functions.

Comment: Of course i referenced it. I edit the post with pictures.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could first manually find the directory where the .h file is located, and then add the path in VS.

[image]

If it doesn't work, I suggest that you could add the path in `Properties->VC++ Directories->Include Directories`.

Also, you could refer to [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1083?view=msvc-160) for more information.

Comment: I did, I searched for it mannualybut nothing. And even when I try this: ` #include "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\programming\cpp\labor1\StaticLibraryExample_v2\MyMathFuncs_v2\mySin.h ` it works, so I don't know what is going on. And I even tried the Include Directories, which you mentioned,